# Returning date as long in entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entity

Hey i need to return Date from table as a long (miliseconds). The column i need to access is on oracle db and is of Timestamp type (name ROW_TMSTP).

What i have done is:

```
@Column(name = "ROW_TMSTP")
@Override
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
public Date getEntityTimeStamp() {
    return entityTS;
}

@Transient
public Long getVersion() {
    return entityTS.getTime();
}
```

that works.. sometimes.
It doesnt work if i want to select records where version is higher than x.

How to write an entity class which would work great on Timestamps as longs?

And please don't try to convince me to change db structure.. I have to stick to what there is and i have to return a field by getVersion.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Lack of mapping in getVersion got my select queries to result in invalid identifier. Removing `@Transient` and adding proper mapping solved the thing.

```
@Column(name="ROW_TMSTP", updatable=false, insertable=false)
public Long getVersion() {
     return entityTS.getTime();
}
```

one was a bit tricky though, compairing long to date... but that is not my problem.

Comment: How did u solve the comparison issue  ?

Comment: explanation is above - not @Transient Long getVersion works.

Answer (score 0):

> It doesnt work if i want to select records where version is higher
>   than x

One Alternate way is ,instead of using version in the where clause , you can convert the long to timestamp and use entityTimestamp in the where clause that should do it i guess

Comment: yep, i got it so, but it means that i have to change about 40 queryString, which i wouldnt like to do.